# creating an object from a muiti valued attribute array

Tags: arrays, powershell

Im using the Auvik Powershell module and the return of some of the commands have some multi-values in them.

What's the best way to turn this into a single value object.

```
type   id                 attributes                                            
----   --                 ----------                                            
tenant 53337108651709 @{domainPrefix=50waters; tenantType=client}            
tenant 58897678651709 @{domainPrefix=BillAve; tenantType=client}
```

=========================================================
Like this======

```
type   id               domain prefix    tenant type
----    ----                   ----            ------
tenant 58897678651709         BillAve          client
tenant 53337108651709       50waters          client
```

Comment: iterate thru the main collection, iterate thru the values stored in the `attributes` property to build an object with those props added to it, and - finally - send that new object to your new collection.

Answer (score 2):

There are more methods and you can see some of them in the following code snippet:

```
'--- Original object'
$objectOrig | Out-Default

'--- Flattened using a `foreach` loop'
$ObjectFlat = foreach ( $line in $objectOrig ) {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        type=$line.type
        id=$line.id
        domainPrefix=$line.attributes.domainPrefix
        tenantType=$line.attributes.tenantType
    }
}
$ObjectFlat | Out-Default

'--- Flattened using calculated properties'
$ObjectFlaX = $objectOrig | Select-Object -Property type, id,
    @{Name='domainPrefix'; Expression={$_.attributes.domainPrefix}},
    @{Name='tenantType'  ; Expression={$_.attributes.tenantType}}
$ObjectFlaX | Out-Default
```

**Output**: `62503286.ps1`

> ```
> --- Original object
>
> type               id attributes
> ----               -- ----------
> tenant 53337108651709 @{domainPrefix=50waters; tenantType=client}
> tenant 58897678651709 @{domainPrefix=BillAve; tenantType=client}
>
>
> --- Flattened using a `foreach` loop
>
> type               id domainPrefix tenantType
> ----               -- ------------ ----------
> tenant 53337108651709 50waters     client
> tenant 58897678651709 BillAve      client
>
>
> --- Flattened using calculated properties
>
> type               id domainPrefix tenantType
> ----               -- ------------ ----------
> tenant 53337108651709 50waters     client
> tenant 58897678651709 BillAve      client
> ```